# Draw the route at runtime

Tags: bing-maps

I have an app with Bing Maps and I need to draw the route of the user dinamically. 
Now I can only trace the user position with a pushpin. Is there some method to draw route?

UPDATE 1:
I'm using this handler assigned to geolocator.positionChanged:

```
private void geolocator_DrawRoute(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Need to get back onto UI thread before updating location information
        this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(
        () =>
        {
            //Get the current location
            Location location = new Location(args.Position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude, 
                args.Position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude);
            _rotta.Add(location);
            if (_rotta.Count > 1)
            {
                var polyline = new MapPolyline { Locations = _rotta, Color = Colors.Blue, Width = 3 };
                _shapeLayer.Shapes.Add(polyline);
            }

            //Update the position of the GPS pushpin
            MapLayer.SetPosition(GpsPushpin, location);

            //Update the map view to the current GPS location
            MyMap.SetView(location, 18);
        }));
    }
```

UPDATE 2:

```
private void geolocator_DrawRoute(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Need to get back onto UI thread before updating location information
        Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(
        () =>
        {
            //Get the current location
            var location = new Location(args.Position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude, args.Position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude);
            _rottaLoc.Add(location);
            if (_rotta == null)
            {
                _rotta = new MapPolyline { Locations = _rottaLoc, Color = Colors.Blue, Width = 4 };
            }
            else
            {
                _rotta.Locations = _rottaLoc;
            }

            _shapeLayer.Shapes.Add(_rotta);

            //Update the position of the GPS pushpin
            MapLayer.SetPosition(GpsPushpin, location);

            //Update the map view to the current GPS location
            MyMap.SetView(location, 18);
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to draw a line as the user moves on the map, i.e. trace their route? or do you want to draw a driving route and show the users location along that route?

Comment: @rbrunditt I want to draw a polyline that follows the user moves! Can I use  the PositionChanged event of the geolocator?

Comment: yes you can use the PositionChanged event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this the first step would be to get the users position. If you are using JavaScript you can use the Geolocation API to get the users location and to monitor them as they move. Here is some documentation on how to do this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/geolocation/trip_meter/

Once you have this done you can show the users location fairly easily. If you want to draw a polyline to should their path then what you can do is the first time users position is grabbed you can create a polyline object where the first and second coordinate are this first coordinate. You can then add the polyline to the map. The next time the users location is grabbed you can simply add this new location to the polyline's array of locations.

Comment: The user position is continuously grabbed. I have a START button and a END button. When the user clicks on start I start to draw the trace until the user clicks stop.

Comment: Right, look at the monitor users location section of the link I provided.

Comment: That code is JavaScript but I'm using C#..See update1 in the first post. Could it work?

Comment: Ok, the same concept works in C#. When the users position is first created you would create a polyline that has two points that are for the same location. When the users position updates you would then append the new location to the array of locations for the polyline you created. You will want to store a reference to the polyline in a variable that way it is easy to access. I recommend creating a global variable that has a null polyline. When the users position updates, if polyline is null create it, otherwise append location to polyline.